# Keeping Adafruit Feather charged

Tags: battery, feather

I'm creating a keyboard for someone using an [Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluetooth LE](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2829) as the brains. The case I want to put in into would be hard to remove to charge the battery.

Can I use this [USB LiIon/LiPoly charger](https://www.adafruit.com/product/259) to charge the LiPo battery and keep power to the board? And then unpluging from the USB mini-B would switch over to the battery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the very page you linked to:

"... we added a connector for any of our 3.7V Lithium polymer batteries and built in battery charging. You don't need a battery, it will run just fine straight from the micro USB connector. But, if you do have a battery, you can take it on the go, then plug in the USB to recharge. The Feather will automatically switch over to USB power when its available. We also tied the battery thru a divider to an analog pin, so you can measure and monitor the battery voltage to detect when you need a recharge."

So, the board has a charger and battery connector already built in.